# Geocode returns ZERO_RESULTS only in my country

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, geocode

Why is it doing that? My country is North Cyprus and whenever I click any place within my country it returns zero_results error code but if I click any other countries place like Turkey and/or Los Angeles, I successfully get the address, city etc.

What can I do?

Comment: I would guess because of the political state of this region(it's e.g. the same with Kashmir and Abkhazia)

Comment: Would suggest trying out with other services. In general the service provideers might for any reason not be able to have the data in their databases for certain areas, and indeed different services are running in different places, and might thus be following different sets of rules.